# Receiving Data From GPS GT06 in java

Tags: gps, java, tracking-server

Am developing a fleet application where i need to track my vehicle movement. and store into mysql db. Am using gt06 gps with a sim card.

Created a java file for checking that gps is sending the data or not. my program is connected with gps but the data am receiving is not clear. can anyone help me out. how to parse the data. or the data am receiving is wrong.

Below program am using

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class BackupServerListener {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ServerListener().startServer();
}

public void startServer() {
    final ExecutorService clientProcessingPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(03);

    Runnable serverTask = new Runnable() {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        public void run() {
            try {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9876);
                System.out.println("Waiting for clients to connect...");
                while (true) {
                    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    clientProcessingPool.submit(new ClientTask(clientSocket));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Unable to process client request");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread serverThread = new Thread(serverTask);
    serverThread.start();
}

private class ClientTask implements Runnable {
    private final Socket clientSocket;

    private ClientTask(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Got a client !");
        while (true) {

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            String clientData = "";

            clientData = reader.readLine();
            String hex_value = asciiToHex(clientData);
            System.out.println("clientdata::::"+hex_value);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     }

    }
    private String asciiToHex(String clientData) {

        char[] chars = clientData.toCharArray();
        StringBuffer hex = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
        {
            hex.append(Integer.toHexString((int)chars[i]));
        }
        return hex.toString();
    }

 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class BackupServerListener {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new BackupServerListener().startServer();
}

!!!!!Instead of !!!!!!!!!!
public class BackupServerListener {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ServerListener().startServer();
}
```

Comment: Hi! Could you add a quick explanation or a source to help understand the context of your answer ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: hi, actually there was an error in your listener constructor  .because when I ran your code after fixing the constructor .the program ran successfully and the GT06 login heartbeat I got. now GPS device needs to send a response from your end. then you will get the actual GPS location data.